# When I start my app, it doesnt work. But if I include it through an icon, then everything works

Tags: android, android-studio

I start the app on phone through Android Studio, it is shown an error in app. If I open application through an icon on my phone, then it works. I think that a problem in AndroidManifest.xml
P.S. If devices isn't in Lolipop, then it doesn't work anyhow.

UPD: I publish my app in Google Play. In Developer Console I received a notification message that an error in Main Activity, onCreate. But I don't found anything here.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.engineers.great.firstapp"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--Below MA which started at first. I can can return here, if I use a  back button -->
        <activity android:name="com.engineers.great.firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
<!-- It's not a main menu lol if you click from MA on "START" then you will be here -->
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
<!-- Below from MA1_! to MA2 are questions and results of my test. I set intent extras in everyone. I don't know, maybe it's important -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1_1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1_2"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1_3"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

       <!-- It's many buttons with different results of test  -->
        <activity android:name=".Sociotypes"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include the stack trace?

Comment: You don't need to add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> ` to every Activity. Remove that and the `intent-filter` tag for all activities, but leave it for `.MainMenu`. Do a clean+rebuild, and see if it works.

Comment: @Drew, I'm sorry, but I don't know what is stack trace. I think you understand that I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any Launcher intent filter in first activity.
Add this in the activity you want to launch first :

```
  <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
```